# What does Float::INFINITY do, and why does it work for this sorting method?

Tags: ruby

I'm working my way through an online program learning Ruby and one of the challenges/lessons was to write a method that takes in an argument of a hash whose values are all numbers and returns the "key" corresponding to the lowest value.

I wrote the following code that passed the test and afterward was shown the "recommended" solution, which of course was much more efficient. Can someone walk me through the second version of the method below and tell me how it accomplishes the task?

For purposes of the challenge, I was not allowed to use any of the following methods:

```
#keys
#values
#min
#sort
#min_by
```

My solution:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)

lowest_key = nil

if name_hash != {}
   value_array=name_hash.collect do |key,value|
     value
   end

   loop do
     swapped = false
     (value_array.length-1).times do |i|
        if value_array[i] > value_array[i+1]
          value_array[i], value_array[i+1] = value_array[i+1], value_array[i]
          swapped=true
        end
     end
     break if not swapped
   end

   name_hash.each do |key,value|
      if value == value_array.first
        lowest_key = key
      end
   end
end
lowest_key
end
```

Recommended solution:

```
def key_for_min_value(hash)
  lowest_key = nil
  lowest_value = Float::INFINITY
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v < lowest_value
      lowest_value = v
      lowest_key = k
    end
  end
  lowest_key
end
```

Comment: You could solve this using reduce as well ``{a: 1, b: 0.1, c: 3, d: 5}.reduce {|a,b| a[1] < b[1] ? a : b}.first``

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, especially http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm46397818492288. Ask good questions and don't worry about how long you've been doing something. "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution works because your hash can't contain a value that is greater than Float::INFINITY so it's guaranteed to trigger the `if` condition at least once.

An alternative would be to set `lowest_value = nil` and then in the condition do

```
if lowest_value.nil? || v < lowest_value
```

but it's not as elegant (and requires another check that will only be true the first iteration.

Another alternative would be to remove the first value in the hash and set that to `lowest_value`, then loop through the rest.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. First iteration, value is compared to infinity and then becomes the "lowest_value" for evaluation in the next iteration. So my verbose exercise of creating an array and sorting was unnecessary. I appreciate the help.